# Text to Speech inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fully working Text-To-Speech inside an activity with an onClick event that works, I would like to move the TTS functionality to one of my Fragments, is this possible ? I seen two questions on this but does not give a correct answer, any help would be much appreciated.

this is my TTS activity.

```
package com.test.finalproject;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class TextTo extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

 private TextToSpeech tts;
 private Button btnSpeak;
 private EditText txtText;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text_to);


//  tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText); //

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

    });
}

  @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    }

  @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

}

private void speakOut() {

    String text = txtText.getText().toString();

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
  }
}
```

MyFragmentA

```
package com.test.finalproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private TextView txtText;


@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
  return myFragmentView;

  tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

  btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

        private void speakOut() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    }
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }



private void onClick_TheSpire()

 {

    }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




}



12-08 21:01:08.717: I/TextToSpeech(1978): Sucessfully bound to com.samsung.SMT
```

12-08 21:01:08.717: D/AndroidRuntime(1978): Shutting down VM
12-08 21:01:08.717: W/dalvikvm(1978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c64da0)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): Process: com.test.finalproject, PID: 1978
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.test.finalproject.MyFragmentA.onCreateView(MyFragmentA.java:32)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2532)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-08 21:01:08.737: E/AndroidRuntime(1978):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutForScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Design Movies Screen"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/thespire" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/theSpire"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="onClick_TheSpire"
    android:text="Directions" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="Speak" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnSpeak"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="The Spire - The huge, striking and innovative monument of the Spire stands in      the middle of O&apos;Connell Street just across from the famous GPO. 120m high and 3m in diameter at the base, the Spire rises above O’Connell Street, breaking above the roof line with as slender and elegant a movement as is technically possible." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is your fragment??? It is not visible in your code!!!

Comment: Ill add it now sorry

Comment: @JamesCgrave "android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button" Make sure your id's match your layout properly.

Comment: They are all matching id's

Comment: Could you post the layout of your fragment? The error from logcat signifies a mismatch between layout and fragment.

Comment: The elements btnSpeak and txtText do match so the error must be elsewhere. From the logcat, I think it mentions line 32 in your fragment. Check the element you're using findViewById on for that line.

Comment: this is the line at 32.                                        txtText = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a method in your activity that will handle the speaking such as:

```
public void speak(String text) {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
  }
}
```

Then in your fragment when you have a String to speak, here's an example implementation:

```
String textToSpeak = "Hello from my fragment";
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
myActivity.speak(textToSpeak);
```

With something like this you'll be able to keep the TTS in your activity but still speak phrases from the fragment.

Here's something to look at in the new code you posted:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

From the documentation the constructor takes a Context and a Listener:

```
TextToSpeech(Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener)
```

Try this instead:

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
```

Furthermore, if you use "this" as the listener, you would have to implement it which you haven't in the posted code.

Comment: i am unsure what you mean @Razz, as far as im aware you cannot use FindById inside a fragment, is this right ?

Comment: Where specifically are you concerned about FindViewById?

Comment: When I added the code into the fragment these lines gave me errors

Comment: So do btnSpeak and txtText now exist in R.layout.fragment_a? Or are they still in the activity layout R.layout.text_to?

Comment: You can still use findViewById in a fragment as long as those id's exist in the fragment's layout. The call would just be adjusted to `btnSpeak = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);`

Comment: There both in the fragment_a.xml

Comment: If that's the case then just adjust the findViewById calls as mentioned above.

Comment: That got rid of them two errors, this is giving me an error with no suggestions.

Comment: tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

Comment: See my comments in the second half of the answer that addressed this line.

Comment: I have changed that line to your example and its still giving me errors, should I implement anything

Comment: Yes you would need to implement the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener as you did in your Activity.

Comment: is it possible to implement two things in the one class, I already have an onClick Implemented

Comment: Yes you can only extend one class, but you can implement multiple.

Comment: this is still giving me an error    tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
  the only suggestion is to remove it

Comment: Move the `return myFragmentView;` line to the end of the onCreateView method. You were returning before the rest of your method finished.

Comment: That got rid of the error, the app is now crashing when I open the fragment?

Comment: What was the logcat output of the error? Add it to your post.

Comment: Also if this was helpful, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: I cant add the logcat as a piece of code? i added it anyway though.